# Pymatgen- Installing modules [pymatgen.apps.borg.queen]

Tags: pip, pymatgen

it is a very basic question but I stuck it.
I have installed pymatgen and following [this phase diagram](http://pymatgen.org/usage.html#simple-example-making-a-phase-diagram) tutorial. WHen I try to import pymatgen.borg it gives me an error
[image]
I guess I need to install pymatgen.borg so to install pymatgen.borg.queen module I used these commands

```
python -m pip install pymatgen.borg.queen
```

But it does not work and I am getting this error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymatgen.borg.queen (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for pymatgen.borg.queen

I have the latest version of python (3.6.5) and pip is upgraded. I tried these names after pip install and so far, none of them have worked: *pymatgen.borg, pymatgen.borg.queen,pymatgen.apps.borg.queen, BorgQueen AbstractDrone(It is like a name of the module)*

Here is the link of the [Borgqueen module](http://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.apps.borg.queen.html#module-pymatgen.apps.borg.queen) If you help me I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

There is no [pymatgen.borg.queen at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pymatgen.borg.queen/). You need to install `pymatgen`:

```
pip install pymatgen
```

The detailed installation instructions are at http://pymatgen.org/#getting-pymatgen

After installation use [`pymatgen.apps.borg.queen`](https://github.com/materialsproject/pymatgen/blob/master/pymatgen/apps/borg/queen.py).

Comment: I installed pymatgen but when I impoert it from python I have this ModuleNotFoundError 'from pymatgen.borg.hive import VaspToComputedEntryDrone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.borg'' What do you suggest me? (I add this error to the question as well as a jpg)

Comment: `borg` is in `pymatgen.apps` and `hive` is in [pymatgen.apps.borg](https://github.com/materialsproject/pymatgen/blob/master/pymatgen/apps/borg/hive.py) so `from pymatgen.apps.borg.hive import VaspToComputedEntryDrone`

Comment: Thank you so much it did work `from pymatgen.apps.borg.hive import VaspToComputedEntryDrone`